# insert_one() got an unexpected keyword argument 'check_keys'

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

I am trying to insert a key with dot in mongodb but it's not working

```
 def mongo(self,product_dict):
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    mydb = myclient["toys_db"]
    mycol = mydb["toys3"]

    mydict = product_dict
    print "First : ",mydict        

    for i in xrange(1): 
        mydict['i'] = i 
        mydict['_id'] = ObjectId() 

        mycol.insert_one(mydict , check_keys= False)
```

Error:

> insert_one() got an unexpected keyword argument 'check_keys'

Comment: Which version of pymongo are you using? Seems that option `check_keys` is not supported

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.22

Comment: [insert_one](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.2.2/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) has only `bypass_document_validation`, [insert](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.2.2/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert) has `check_keys`, but it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version as of today, `insert_one()` by default has `check_keys=False`.

Hence, there should be no explicit need to specify any argument.

[image: library code]

[image: library code definition]